# Crash and Timout in HttpWebRequest, GetRequestStream

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mono, xsp

Our company is working on a Transformation Service to alter incoming and outgoing SOAP XML requests. The reason for this is that is the fact that our specific server stack which uses the Mono framework doesn't have very good SOAP support, and we need to manually transform the messages while in transit so they confirm with our clients system.
We are running the service on an up to date ubuntu machine on the LTS release cycle, and using XSP4 web server, since we were unable to configure mod_mono to support SOAP transmissions

However, our transformation service isn't working very well. We are getting an issue while it is calling HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream, it throws the error below, and after about a minute, it times out.

```
Missing method .ctor in assembly /opt/mono/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0_b77a5c561934e089/System.dll, type Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.CertificateValidationCallback2
```

We cannot figure out what is causing this issue, and it is holding up our clients from doing UAT of our system, as our respective systems are unable to communicate data between them.

Can anyone shed some light in this issue?

Comment: seems like a broken mono install, so please state the version of Mono that you're running and how did you install it

Comment: I haven't configured the server, but as far as I know it is the current uptodate version running on ubuntu (so 2.10.8.1). We were trying to get it to run standalone with XSP4, but got this error. Running it from Monodevelop, however, works fine.

Comment: check if you have a "Mono.Security.dll" file in your bin folder, and if yes, remove it. If this is not the case, I would simply upgrade to mono 3.x

Comment: As far as i know Ubuntu has no support for mono 3.x, need to wait for badgerports to release a new version. 2.10.8.1 is the latest available for any Linux OS